# Counting how many times a condition is true within each group

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I'm using a simulated dataset with many groups (+2mil) where I want to count the total number of observations and the number of observations above a threshold (here it is 2) for each one of my groups.

It seems much faster when I create a flag variable, especially for `dplyr` and a little bit faster for `data.table`.

Why does this happen? How does it work in the background in each case?

Check my examples below.

**Simulated dataset**

```
# create an example dataset
set.seed(318)

N = 3000000 # number of rows

dt = data.frame(id = sample(1:5000000, N, replace = T),
                value = runif(N, 0, 10))
```

**Using dplyr**

```
library(dplyr)

# calculate summary variables for each group
t = proc.time()
dt2 = dt %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(N = n(),
                                        N2 = sum(value > 2))
proc.time() - t

# user  system elapsed
# 51.70    0.06   52.11


# calculate summary variables for each group after creating a flag variable
t = proc.time()
dt2 = dt %>% mutate(flag = ifelse(value > 2, 1, 0)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>% summarise(N = n(),
                             N2 = sum(flag))
proc.time() - t

# user  system elapsed
# 3.40    0.16    3.55
```

**Using data.table**

```
library(data.table)

# set as data table
dt2 = setDT(dt, key = "id")


# calculate summary variables for each group
t = proc.time()
dt3 = dt2[, .(N = .N,
              N2 = sum(value > 2)), by = id]
proc.time() - t

# user  system elapsed 
# 1.93    0.00    1.94 


# calculate summary variables for each group after creating a flag variable
t = proc.time()
dt3 = dt2[, flag := ifelse(value > 2, 1, 0)][, .(N = .N,
                                                 N2 = sum(flag)), by = id]
proc.time() - t

# user  system elapsed 
# 0.33    0.04    0.39
```

Comment: For `data.table`: `sum(var)` and `.N` are gforce optimised. But not yet for `sum(expr)`.. Add `verbose = TRUE` and see the difference in the optimised expressions. We'll work on catching these cases better in the future.

Comment: Note: you don't need to set key for grouping/join operations anymore.. It's fine if you want to key.. but just so you know, it's not necessary.

Comment: In `data.table` I suspect a difference is that the data.table is already sorted in the second instance, so you are not counting that. Try putting `dt2 = setDT(dt, key = "id")` above each instance.

Comment: @lmo, ah good point, if OP didn't recreate `dt` for each timing.

Comment: @Arun I don't think the ordering is the issue. I get similar timing if I time the two approaches in reverse order.

Comment: Pre-keying provides a  a relatively minor speed up in the first `data.table` instance on my machine, from elapsed = 2.30 to elapsed = 1.95.

Comment: @Roland, yes, I'd expect that.. I'm quite certain it's due to internal optimisations to avoid `eval()` for each group. lmo's point is still useful because it helps establish the case clearly without any other factors.

Comment: @lmo I will correct that just to eliminate that possibility (faster due to ordering). I checked by re-running the 2 approaches the other way around, but the right thing is for me to correct it.

Comment: If you're on `v1.9.7`, optimisations are also documented under `?\`datatable-optimize\``

Comment: @Arun Possibly it also plays a role that one approach does the logical comparison for all rows whereas the other does it by grouping?

Comment: @Roland, there are `2255856` groups.. Eval-ing would become significant on that many.. sum(expr that evalutes to logical) usually wouldn't be that time consuming.. but it would add up for these many groups. So yes, that could be as well. Adding `verbose=TRUE` usually tells the time spent on eval part alone..

Comment: Just using the logical comparison (`flag := value > 2`) will give you a further speed increase.

Comment: Very interesting that it speeds up `data.table` but makes `dplyr` slower if I use `mutate(flag = value > 2)`...

Answer (score 1):

**The issue with dplyr is that the sum function is used with an expression and a high number of IDs/groups.** From what Arun is saying in the comments, I guess the issue with data.table is similar.

Consider the code below: I reduced it to the bare minimum that is necessary to illustrate the problem. dplyr is slow when summing an expression, even if the expression involves only the identity function, so the performance issues have nothing to do with the greater than comparison operator. In contrast, dplyr is fast when summing a vector. A even greater performance gain is achieved by reducing the number of IDs/groups from one million to ten.

The reason is that [hybrid evaluation](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/vignettes/internals/hybrid-evaluation.Rmd), i.e., evaluation in C++, works only if sum is used with a vector. With an expression as argument, the evaluation is done in R, which adds overhead for each group. The details are in the linked vignette. From the profile of the code, it seems that the overhead mainly comes from the tryCatch error handling function.

```
##########################
### many different IDs ###
##########################

df <- data.frame(id = 1:1e6, value = runif(1e6))

# sum with expression as argument
system.time(df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(sum(identity(value))))
#    user  system elapsed
#  80.492   0.368  83.251

# sum with vector as argument
system.time(df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(sum(value)))
#    user  system elapsed
#   1.264   0.004   1.279


#########################
### few different IDs ###
#########################

df$id <- rep(1:10, each = 1e5)

# sum with expression as argument
system.time(df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(sum(identity(value))))
#    user  system elapsed
#   0.088   0.000   0.093

# sum with vector as argument
system.time(df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(sum(value)))
#    user  system elapsed
#   0.072   0.004   0.077


#################
### profiling ###
#################

df <- data.frame(id = 1:1e6, value = runif(1e6))

profvis::profvis({ df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(sum(identity(value))) })
```

Code profile:

[image: Code profile]